# How do I know what connections has my debian server blocked?

Tags: debian, iptables, logging

In short, I am actually looking for the log files to see any incoming connection being blocked in debian lenny server.

Or any other way to know? I am using iptables

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add a rule at the end of your chains to send the packet to the `LOG` target before letting it run into the default `DENY` policy.

Answer (score 1):

By default, dropped packets aren't logged.  This can be a huge amount of traffic if you enable it, and syslog by default will write messages to the disc in the most "safe" mode, which causes heavy disc I/O loading.  So be careful that this doesn't end up flooding your server.

To enable logging of dropped or rejected packets, I would recommend adding a LOG rule before the DROP/REJECT rule, something like this:

```
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 4/sec --limit-burst 20 -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropping  (FORWARD): " 
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

This uses the "limit" module to allow up to 20 packets to be logged before it starts limiting them to no more than 4 per second.  It'll allow 20 more packets once the 4/second limit hasn't been hit for a while.

There's also the "hashlimit" module which may be available on your system that allows you to have a unique limit per remote or local IP address.  See "man iptables" for more information on hashlimit.

Finally, you probably want to write your log messages to a destination where you have disabled fsync.  On older systems this was done by putting a "-" at the beginning of the file name in /etc/syslog.conf.  I'm not seeing a similar option for rsyslog, so just be aware of it and if you see disc I/O go through the roof when you log a lot of packets, you may need to add stronger limits or look into changing rsyslog's configuration.

Comment: Where it supposed to log to? Is it supposed to go \var\log\syslog? Pardon if this is newbie question.

Comment: By default, it would log to /var/log/syslog I believe.